# Logout keyboard shortcut keys in Linux Mint?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, logout

I am trying to logout without using mouse. Are you aware of any key combination that will do the trick?

Comment: Which desktop environment do you use? Cinnamon, Mate or something else? 
Anyway I guess that it could be set somewhere in the Settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks szkj for your hint. I went to keyboard setting. The default shortcut 
"Ctrl+Alt+Del" was not giving the logout option. So I used the new key map of "Alt+L" and it is working now. I am using Cinnamon btw.[image]

Comment: +1 worked for me - though, using Mate, I need to get to the Keyboard Shortcuts menu in some other way and it looks different

Comment: @RobertG : then add the the solution for mate as an additional answer to this question - this would be absolutely valid. Even if it will not get the accepted status, you will help other users with that package.

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach good point - I should have done that back then. I have changed to another system since (currently using gnome on Ubuntu)... In general, I find the default UI to change these settings changes a lot really fast, and my only reliable way of changing all unwanted hotkeys (such as CTRL+ALT+directions) is changing the config in dconf editor... This is out of scope of this question, though.

Comment: @RobertG perhaps worth its own question? ;)